# Issue with unit conversion

Tags: units

I am getting an error converting energy unit Pa*m^3 (Pascal * Meters^3) to J (Joules).

```
pi = Quantity[2.00*10^5, "Pascals"];
Vi = Quantity[4.00*10^-6, ("Meters")^3];
Vf = Quantity[8.00*10^-6, ("Meters")^3];
gamma = 1.4;
W = pi*Vi^(gamma)*Integrate[V^(-gamma), {V, Vi, Vf}]
```

Answer: 0.484283 m^3*Pa

When I try to convert to Joules:

```
UnitConvert[W, "Joules"]
```

I get an error message:
Meters^3 Pascals and Joules are incompatible units.
Also, I noticed the unit m^3 is actually m^2.999999.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message says:

`(Meters)^3. Pascals and Joules are incompatible units`, Notice the decimal point at the end of `3`. Using `Rationalize` fixes it.

```
pi = Quantity[2.00*10^5, "Pascals"];
Vi = Quantity[4.00*10^-6, "Meters"^3];
Vf = Quantity[8.00*10^-6, ("Meters")^3];
gamma = 1.4;
W = pi*Vi^(gamma)*Integrate[V^(-gamma), {V, Vi, Vf}] // Rationalize

UnitConvert[W, "Joules"]
```

> Quantity[0.484283, "Joules"]

Answer (score 2):

Use an exact (rational) exponent γ:

```
pi = Quantity[2.00*10^5, "Pascals"];
Vi = Quantity[4.00*10^-6, ("Meters")^3];
Vf = Quantity[8.00*10^-6, ("Meters")^3];
gamma = 14/10;

W = pi*Vi^(gamma)*Integrate[V^(-gamma), {V, Vi, Vf}]
(*    Quantity[0.484283, ("Meters")^3 "Pascals"]    *)

UnitConvert[W, "Joules"]
(*    Quantity[0.484283, "Joules"]    *)
```